# Understanding formulation for Markov chain

Tags: probability, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

There is a formulation for Markov chains that I don't understand. Consider a Markov Chain $\textbf{X}=\{X_n:n=0,1,...\}$, with arbitrary state space $S$ with countably generated $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}$.

I know there is this post explaining what a countably generated $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}$ is: [What is a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra? Can't find a definition online](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456416/what-is-a-countably-generated-sigma-algebra-cant-find-a-definition-online).

Does this formulation include Markov chains on countable spaces?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the set of events $\{X_n=k\}$ with $n$ and $k$ being integers, or with $n \in \{n=0,1,\ldots\}$ and $k \in S$.  Is that a countable set? Does that generate $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: As the set of event $\{X_n=k\}$ is countable, and the union and intersection is countable as well I would say that it does generate $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: So that implies that the answer to your question is ...?

Comment: Therefore, it does include Markov chain on countable spaces.